# Как TSCON влияет на других пользователей?

Tags: windows, cmd, rdp

Я подключаюсь к удаленной машине по RDP для выполнения на ней автотестов, я использую команду на удаленной машине

```
tscon 2 /dest:console
```

для того что при отключении от RDP драйвер Internet Explorer мог работать и выполнять тесты. Но вот вопрос, к этой удаленной машине подключаются множество пользователей для своих целей. Если я буду использовать эту команду и подключатся к console это повлияет как-то на других пользователей? Их будет выкидывать или может быть еще что? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Подключись и узнай)))

Comment: Не хотелось бы экспериментировать наугад, не хочу кому-то что-то сломать)